# Error Trying to Log In to Wells Fargo via Chromedriver 2.34, Selenium 3.8, and Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, onlinebanking

I am trying to write a program that will log me in to my Wells Fargo account. However, after running my code, it just takes me to the same page and doesn't log me in. I tried putting the log in section in a loop and it continuously loops.

Here is the code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://connect.secure.wellsfargo.com/auth/login/present?
origin=cob&error=yes&LOB=CONS&destination=AccountSummary')

userID = browser.find_element_by_name('j_username')
userID.clear()
userID.send_keys('my_username')

password = browser.find_element_by_name('j_password')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('my_password')

password.submit()

time.sleep(5)
browser.quit
```

Below is a screenshot.

[image: Error code and web page I can't get past]

And here is the copy pasted error code I receive :

```
[9152:6848:1218/202615.262:ERROR:service_manager.cc(157)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface: blink::mojom::ReportingServiceProxy exposed by: content_browser
```

I've tried googling that error code along with key phrases and parts of the error code and have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Perhaps try clicking the 'Sign On' button?

Comment: I tried identifying the click button element through its id and name and then using the .click() method, but I got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a temporary work around using Firefox instead. Firefox never gave me the originally posted error. However, when I tried using Firefox it sent me to a captcha page. Through sheer luck while retesting the program, I clicked on the console window from the geckodriver and learned that if you are clicked in a different window (any window it appears), Wells Fargo does not send you to the captcha page and logs you in to your account. So I modified my code to open up a second browser and close it while it's entering in info.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser2 = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://connect.secure.wellsfargo.com/auth/login/present?origin=cob&error=yes&LOB=CONS&destination=AccountSummary')
userID = browser.find_element_by_id("j_username")
userID.clear()
userID.send_keys('my_username')
password = browser.find_element_by_id("j_password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys('my_password')
browser.find_element_by_name("continue").click()
browser2.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

To login into your **`Wells Fargo`** account you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://connect.secure.wellsfargo.com/auth/login/present?origin=cob&error=yes&LOB=CONS&destination=AccountSummary')
userID = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='j_username']")
userID.clear()
userID.send_keys('my_username')
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='j_password']")
password.clear()
password.send_keys('my_password')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='continue' and @type='submit']").click()
browser.quit()
```

> **Note** : As you see the error as **`ReportingServiceProxy exposed by: content_browser`** you can try including the absolute pat of the **`chromedriver`** binary.

---

### Update :

If you still face the same issue (after going through [**`Error: Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface`**](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/qWAaUwjZpnM) and [**`"service_manager:connector" prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface`**](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-mojo/fOPYqYMfJGE)) I would suggest to uninstall **`Chrome Browser`** through **`Revo Uninstaller`** and run **`CCleaner`** to wipe oout all the OS chores and install **`Chrome Browser`** afresh.

Comment: I'll try this. Do you have any info on why I was getting the above error? Is there a reason using the xpath method will work?

Comment: Well, name attributes `j_username` and `j_password` are within `<input>` tag. So inturn we are helping Selenium locate our `WebElements` faster which increases the performance of our Test Execution.

Comment: I habe also tried finding them by id and got the same result. I have witnessed the firs part of the code executing amd filling in the username and password, it seems to specifically be happening when I try to submit or identify the click button element and use the click method. How will increasing the performance of the test execution preventing this error from occurring?

Comment: Does my script fail on at your end? It does everything at my end. Are using latest **Selenium**, **WebDriver** and **Web Browser**?

Comment: I just got home and tried it. Yes it fails with the same error I was getting from the OP. Yes I just downloaded and installed Selenium and Webdriver today. Chrome was just updated today as well.

Comment: Am i missing something easy like the chrome webdriver executable needs to be in the same directory as the .py file? Or does the .py file need to be ran from the command line?

Comment: No, you can keep `chrome webdriver executable` any where within in your system and explicitly mention the absolute location of the `chrome webdriver executable` through `executable_path` argument as per my answer.